# How do I format numbers with thousand commas in custom infobox in Carto?

Tags: carto

For example, I'm calling a number into the infobox using the following code:

{{med_value}}

The value is 1155000, but I want it to display as 1,155,000.

Is there a way to do that without having to reformat the column as a string and adding the commas that way?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using PostgreSQL instead of {{mustache}}. First, create a new column. Rename it as `formatted`. Then, run the following SQL query to format your numeric field (`med_value`) as you wish:

```
UPDATE 
  name_table
SET
  formatted = TO_CHAR(med_value, '999,999.99')
```

Finally, add an infowindow showing the `formatted` field and voilá!

[image]

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html) you have more info about `TO_CHAR` function.

Comment: While this works, it's not necessarily a great idea to create derived columns just for formatting -- easy to forget on data update --and this is the kind of thing you should be delegating to moustache or even css. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114435/in-mustache-templating-is-there-an-elegant-way-of-expressing-a-comma-seperated-l